# Lifting functions in scala

Tags: scala

I want to define lifting with implicits. Suppose we have a function A => B, I want to define how to lift it to Maybe, i.e. Maybe[A] => Maybe[B].

This can be simply done with implicit conversions. However, if I want to do the same with functions with two or more parameters, I have a problem. The only solutionI know is to duplicate the code.

I want to implement such lifting for arbitrary functions with any number of parameters without duplication. Is this possible in Scala?

Comment: This might be worth looking at: http://blog.tmorris.net/lifting/

Comment: Take a look at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function2, notice tupled function. Also http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function$ tupled and untupled methods.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `F` has a functor instance available, it's possible to lift any function `A => B` to `F[A] => F[B]`.

If `F` has an applicative functor instance available, it's possible to lift any function `A => B => C => .. => Z` to `F[A] => F[B] => F[C] => .. => F[Z]`. Essentially, applicative functor is a generalization of functor for arbitrary arity.

You can learn about functor and applicative functors [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_Functors) and [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids). There is also [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMGCDph1fNY) excellent talk which covers these ideas.

Scalaz library provides these abstractions (and more!).

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val foo: Int => String = _.toString
foo: Int => String = <function1>

scala> foo.lift[Option]
res0: Option[Int] => Option[String] = <function1>

scala> res0(Some(3))
res1: Option[String] = Some(3)

scala> res0(None)
res2: Option[String] = None

scala> val add: (Int, Int) => Int = _ + _
add: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> add.lift[Option]
res3: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) => Option[Int] = <function2>

scala> res3(Some(2), Some(1))
res4: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> res3(Some(2), None)
res5: Option[Int] = None

scala> res3(None, None)
res6: Option[Int] = None
```

Scalaz pimps `lift` method on `Function2`, `Function3` etc because curried functions being syntactially heavier are used less often. Behind the scenes, the lifting happens with `Function1`s (i.e. curried functions).

You might also want to take a look at [Scalaz source code](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/).

Comment: Oddly enough `foo.lift[Option]` doesn't compile with Scalaz 7, but `add.lift[Option]` does

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, Just making a guess here... 1. `Functor[Option].lift(foo)` and `Applicative[Option].lift2(add)` might work. There are less "extension methods" out in the open now. 2. Most extension methods are still available in a package `scalaz.syntax`. The `lift` you are looking for might be lying there.

Comment: is the above code supposed to work on Scalaz 7.1 and Scala 2.11.5?